# Proof of Equivalence relation ~ on $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ such that $(a,b)$~$(c,d)$ when $a+b=c+d$

Tags: equivalence-relations

Define a relation ~ on $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ such that $(a,b)$~$(c,d)$ when $a+b=c+d$.

To prove ~ is an equivalence relation, I need to prove reflexive, symmetric, transitive, right? For the reflexive, $(a,a)$~$(a,a)$, that is $a+a=a+a$. For the symmetric, if $(a,b)$~$(c,d)$, then, $(c,d)$~$(a,b)$. That is If $a+b=c+d$, then $c+d=a+b$??
For the transitive, I need help!

Comment: For reflexive, your check is incomplete: need to check $(a, b) \sim (b, a)$.

Comment: Actually, to prove reflexive you need to check $(a,b) \sim (a,b)$.

Comment: Thanks, How about the symmetric?

Answer (score 3):

To show it's transitive, you need to show that if $a + b = c+d$ and $c+d = e+f$ then $a+b = e+f$.

Answer (score 2):

In general, if $f\colon X\to Y$ is a map, the relation $\sim_f$ defined on $X$ by
$$
a\sim_f b\qquad\text{if and only if}\qquad f(a)=f(b)
$$
is an equivalence relation. All three properties are very easy to verify.

Your relation is a special case of this one, by considering the function $f\colon\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$ defined by
$$
f\colon (a,b)\mapsto a+b
$$

If you don't want to use this general fact, you have to do the checks right: the reflexive property means that, for all $(a,b)\in\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ it holds
$$
(a,b)\sim (a,b)
$$
Remember it should hold for *every* element of the set. Similarly, the symmetry is
$$
\text{if $(a,b)\sim (c,d)$, then $(c,d)\sim (a,b)$}
$$
and the transitivity is
$$
\text{if $(a,b)\sim(c,d)$ and $(c,d)\sim(e,f)$, then $(a,b)\sim(e,f)$.}
$$
Just apply the definition of $\sim$.

Comment: Yes. Whenever I see a question about equivalence relations of this sort, this exact argument comes to mind. This is a classical example for "abstraction makes it simpler". And it's a freshman level one, too!

Comment: @AsafKaragila It's the abstraction of every day activities, such as subdividing people by height, cars by color, food by calories and so on.